# WSO2 API Manager adding extra server node

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

If I have WSO2 API Manager running and want to add an extra node (say I have 2 and want to add a third), it seems that API xml files are not propagated to the synapse-configs directory.

Is there any way to synchronize the apis to a new node?

Similarly, if I have WSO2 API Manager running on a shared database and delete the instance but keep the DB, is there a way to restore the APIs from the DB?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I have WSO2 API Manager running and want to add an extra node (say
>   I have 2 and want to add a third), it seems that API xml files are not
>   propagated to the synapse-configs directory.
>
> Is there any way to synchronize the apis to a new node?

[Deployment Synchronizer](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/SVN-based+Deployment+Synchronizer) provides capability to synchronize deployment artifacts across the nodes of a product cluster. For your cluster to perform correctly, all nodes must have the same configurations.

All Carbon-based products, including WSO2 API Manager use [Deployment Synchronizer](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/SVN-based+Deployment+Synchronizer) (DepSync) to ensure the same status is maintained across all nodes in the cluster. It maintains a central repository of the `<APIM_HOME>/repository/deployment/server` folder, which is where deployment configurations are stored for all Carbon-based products, and uses that repository to synchronize the nodes.

> Similarly, if I have WSO2 API Manager running on a shared database and
>   delete the instance but keep the DB, is there a way to restore the
>   APIs from the DB?

Since some of the parameters are kept in the file system, you can't restore the API only from DB.